# Button only works on double tapping while on remote debugging in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

The problem is when ever, i use remote debugging i needs to double tap a button in order to execute an redux action. I dont know why its happening, am using firebase inorder to signin with email and password.

My Redux Action:

```
 export const loginRequest = (email, password) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SPINNER, payload: true })
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((data) => {
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data })
            NavigationService.navigate('Drawer')
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SPINNER, payload: false })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_UNSUCCESS, payload: error.message })
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SPINNER, payload: false })
            console.log(error)
        })
  }
}
```

So from above, one my first tap `dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SPINNER, payload: true })` it works ( as i can see actions in remote debugging ) and it stops there itself, and again on second tap the firebase function gets executed and its works.

Where is the problem  ? In redux or firebase ? Please guide me through to figure this out !

Comment: If you click somewhere else (outside the button, any blank area) the second time, does your action still trigger? Also if you disable debug mode is the double click problem still exist?

Comment: OMG yes, if i click somewhere else outside the button for second time it works . How is this even possible ? And Once i disable debug, it works fine ! I can get through all in a single tap.

Comment: How to solve this outside clicking problem ? @Andus

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem when developing with React Native.

This is not a problem of redux or firebase, but a minor bug of the react-native debugger. It only happens if you make an api call in debug mode, the result will not be updated unless you tab anywhere on the screen once more after the api call is done.

I don't have a solution to 'fix' that but the delay will not be existed anymore in the released version (or if you disable debug mode) so I think you may just ignore it.

Comment: Understood, thanks :) But i haven't faced this problem before, I was implementing same thing for this new app but facing this. Its weird !

Comment: Btw for you info, I did not use firebase but I also used redux and redux thunk to make api call and I am having this problem since day one :P

Comment: Lol, understood :) ! Thanks bud